# Installer - grub-mount stuck forever

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 17.04.

However, the installer is stuck at proceeding step 4.

This is where the installer is stuck at:

[image]

Therefore, I checked the system monitor and find out that the process `grub-mount` is taking a lot of CPU (The reason why it is just taking less than 50% CPU is that I limited processes to only be able to take 1 logical CPU, if I didn't do so, it will use 100% and my computer will then be stuck):

[image]

The process is:

```
grub-mount /dev/sdb1 /var/lib/os-prober/mount
```

I have been testing Ubuntu 16.04.1, 16.04.2, 16.04.3 and 17.10 installers, they all experience the same problem, `grub-mount` is taking all the resources.

I tried killing the process `grub-mount` using:

```
sudo kill -9 8914
sudo pkill grub-mount
```

but `grub-mount` will just appear over and over again with a different pid.

What should I do to prevent `grub-mount` from running? Or, is there a way to make `grub-mount` run successfully?

Comment: You could try to do a CLI-installing (Ubuntu server, for example). If got successfully, install ubuntu-desktop over it. If that works, you save the day. Just a suggestion, please.

Comment: I just tried: by checking `top` , I found that it is also stuck at running `grub-mount`.